# Meteorological Data API with Python

Tags: meteorology, software

I have a number of points in Europe I would like meteorological data for. More specifically, I am looking for data that is relevant in Air Quality models, like wind, temperature and humidity.

The time frame I am looking for data is in the time interval 2015-2018. Preferably it's hourly data.

Is there any API I can use that gives me the data I need given longitudes and latitudes as input?

Comment: You can use e.g. ERA5 data. Not sure if the api provides access to specific longitudes or latitudes, but you can easily use their api to retrieve the data you want and afterwards extract specific locations from the grib or netcdf file. https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/api-how-to + https://climate.copernicus.eu/climate-reanalysis

Comment: @J.Fregin Thank you, that's quite useful. I also found a question on StackOverflow that asks how to extract data from a grib file given longitude and latitude values... So, maybe these can be combined.